# How to set static property from constructor on EC6

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to create a base class which allows me to set the static property of a React Component through the constructor. The below code is an excerpt of my final solution but I can't get it to work.

When I setup the following class using React Native it doesn't let me set the static property in the constructor. Any ideas how to set a static with a constructor? I need to be able to set the title from a child class.

It always just shows 'first title' on my navigation component.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'first title',
  };

  constructor(){
    super();
    HomeScreen.navigationOptions.title = 'second title';
  }
```

Comment: What exactly does that mean, "doesn't let me"?

Comment: Sorry when react-native instantiates the component.

Comment: I updated it ok?

Comment: Why do you update it in the constructor in the first place? That means the HomeScreen's title is "first title", *until* it has been instantiated once after which it's "second title"…?!

Comment: This is just an excerpt. I want to be able to create a base class which encloses that static type, as I don't want to couple the static type to all copies of my component. I want to shift it out and then just use a constructor to set the title.

Comment: This is not ES6. You may want to show how you use `HomeScreen.navigationOptions.title`. The fact that you only see "first title" doesn't imply that this code doesn't work.

Comment: Mutating global state like `navigationOptions` doesn't make any sense. The whole point of react is to store everything in `state` and `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want to set title as a function of props. Pass the prop(s) as nav params and you will have access to them like this:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title: `Profile for ${navigation.state.params.profileName}`
});
```